# Why none any signals raised on application exited NORMALLY?

Tags: linux, signals

I write a library, register signal handler in function that application always called. I register following signals:

- SIGQUIT
- SIGINT
- SIGKILL
- SIGCHLD
- SIGHUP
- SIGSTOP
- SIGTERM

All signal handlers point to same function just like that:

```
signal(SIGQUIT,signal_handler);
signal(SIGINT,signal_handler);
signal(SIGKILL,signal_handler);
....
```

When I run the application, and exited **NORMALLY**, there aren't any signals raised at all.
But if I break it with `<ctrl-c>`, `SIGINT` will raised and my signal handler is triggered,too.
Why aren't any signals raised when the application exited normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's how it works.  Signals are only raised when something abnormal happens.

If you want to run something when the program exits normally, try using `atexit()` or `on_exit()`.

Comment: That's a BIG surprise to me. You really give me a lesson, thanks very much!